# Why did Cersei and Jaime not go after the person that knew their secret?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S01E01, we see that Jaime and Cersei are aware that Jon Arryn was aware of their "secret". So why didn't they murder him?

Comment: Do we know how much time passed between his knowledge of the secret and his death? They did not straight up murder Ned Stark either...

Comment: It takes a while to plan a murder. Jon Arryn was one of the highest officials of the whole kingdom - it's not easy to murder someone like that, much less get away with it. Panicking and rushing with a "solution" is #1 reason why criminals get caught :)

Comment: @close-voter Uh, no stupid close-reasons please. And please don't delete your automatically generated close-reason comments just because you know they're stupid. If you see behaviour that you deem questionable, feel free to flag it for moderators rather than coming up with non-sense close-reasons against the question. Thank you.

Comment: I rolled back yout title edit. We have a "no spoilers in titles" policy here. I would personally agree that it is not so much a spoiler at all, but members of the community were considering it a spoiler and especially with shows like *Game of Thrones* this can become dangerous territory fast. I think, though, the current title is a reasonable compromise and hope you respect the community's preferences in this regard. Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short, **because they did not have to**.

Jon Arryn was actively investigating Jaime and Cersei's secret when he met his untimely demise. If they were putting a plan together to murder Jon Arryn based on this knowledge it ended up not making a difference because he was killed anyway.

Look at what happened to Ned Stark: he made the same accusations and was not murdered outright. He was taken into custody and put on trial. Given that Jon Arryn was in the same position, a likely similar route events would have taken place.

The person who was in the way for Jaime and Cersei was not Jon Arryn or Ned Stark, it was *Robert Baratheon*... and they *did* have a plan to murder him...

Comment: Case 1: So it seems that the "murderer" did exactly what Cersei and Jamie wanted to do and that too at a perfect timing! The only difference being in the purpose. The murderer's motive had nothing to do with Jon's knowledge of the secret.

Comment: What do you think of this case 2: They were not aware of Jon's knowledge of their secret prior to his death but came to know about it from his last words?

Comment: Case 1) I think the *real murderer* knew of the secret and saw it as an opportunity to start/further his plot.  --- Case 2) That could be possible...